# make a div element stick to the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, css

I have wrote a script to detect when I reach the div element which is a navigation bar and then I change it's css to position fixed and top 0 so it will be fixed to the top, the problem that it doesn't do that, it acts like scroll to top and it jumps to the beginning of the screen. (it's flickers)

Javascript

```
        var currentScrollTop = 0;
        var barMenuOriginalTopPos = $('#navigation').offset().top;
        console.log('original:' + barMenuOriginalTopPos);
        $(window).scroll(function() {

            currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            console.log(currentScrollTop);
            if(currentScrollTop >= barMenuOriginalTopPos && $('#navigation').hasClass('fixElementToTop') == false){
                $('#navigation').addClass('fixElementToTop');
            }
            else if(currentScrollTop < barMenuOriginalTopPos && $('#navigation').hasClass('fixElementToTop') ){
                $('#navigation').removeClass('fixElementToTop');
            }
        });
```

CSS

```
.fixElementToTop { position: fixed; top:0; z-index:100;}
```

Why

Comment: Did any answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a css fixed bar on top of the screen

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px">Nav bar</div>
```

Review:

sorry i didn't understand your initial question, here it goes, to avoid it flicking you should start the object with a fixed position, lets say:

```
<div style="height:120px">XXX</div>
<div id="navigation" style="position: fixed; top:120; z-index:100;">Navigation</div>
<div class="win" style="border: 1px solid; height: 900px;"></div>
```

the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    currentScrollTop = 120-$(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(currentScrollTop);
    if (currentScrollTop<0) currentScrollTop=0
    $("#navigation")[0].style.top=currentScrollTop+"px";
});​
```

Comment: can someone indicate a jquery for this part .style.top=currentScrollTop+"px"; ?

Comment: the issue might be caused due to the $(window).scroll since it fires the event dozen of times as long as you scroll. so the solution might be if I handle one event and then I will do unbind. is it right?

Comment: i would keep it just like that because you might need to scroll back, and anyway you have to do the checking

Comment: The thing is that on chrome, it keeps flickering (scrolling to the top when I add the class to set the position)

Comment: don't set the class, its the class setting that makes the flick, the elements must be position fixed from the beggining, see the fiddle above

Answer (score 3):

Here an *non flickering solution* via a jQuery plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fixedElement').scrollToFixed({ marginTop: 0 });
});
```

**Live example**: http://bigspotteddog.github.com/ScrollToFixed/
**Plugin's website**: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed/

Answer (score 2):

Set this line

```
var barMenuOriginalTopPos = $('#navigation').offset().top;
```

as

```
var barMenuOriginalTopPos = $('#navigation').offset().top + 6;
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/7xwxE/1/)**

Comment: it still flickers (goes to top).